# Can you use the Duelist Prowess Attack Power only once during combat in 4e?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, rogue

The DM is seeing it as since the secondary says daily, it can be used once.

I understand that the stance is active until end of combat, stance change, or unconscious.

The Stance is a daily power.

But the Duelist Prowess attack power shows its little power bar color is also a **daily** and **dailies** can only be used once until an extended rest, correct?

So I would only be able to use the secondary power once even though the stance is still active or does it work a different way?

I found this page [How often can secondary powers be used?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/15223/how-often-can-secondary-powers-be-used) that gives great examples, but it says that the specific wording in the parent power trumps the general rule of the secondary power being a daily.

With that said this is what the power says.

> **Duelist's Prowess**
>
> *The way you stand appears to allow a foe an opening, but in truth your skill is such that you use your foe’s attack to draw it in for your own quick strike.*
>
> **Daily,        Martial, Stance,**
>   **Minor Action,      Personal**
>
> **Effect:** Until the stance ends, each time an enemy hits or misses you, you can use the Duelist's Prowess Attack power against it.
>
> > **Duelist's Prowess Attack**
> >
> > **Daily,      Martial, Weapon,**
> >     **Immediate Interrupt,      Melee weapon**
> >
> > **Requirement:** The power Duelist's Prowess must be active in order to use this power.
> >
> > **Requirement:** You must be wielding a light blade.
> >
> > **Trigger:** An enemy adjacent to you attacks you
> >
> > **Target:** The triggering enemy
> >
> > **Attack:** Dexterity vs. Reflex
> >
> > **Hit:** 1[W] + Dexterity modifier damage.

Also if you can point me to any specific pages in the books or compendium that say the power specifics trump general ruling that would be great.

Comment: Somewhat related information: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/36792/responding-to-opportunity-attacks-with-snarling-wolf-stance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### No.

Duelist's Prowess is a daily power that causes you to assume a stance.

While in this stance, you can make an attack when certain conditions are met.

The attack is just an attack; it is not a daily power, even though the ability to use it is granted by a daily power.  You may make the attack as often as the trigger suggests (although it's an immediate interrupt, so it will likely be chiefly limited by the fact that most characters only get one immediate action per round).

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. But because in the character builder and the compendium the bar above the secondary is listed as daily my DM views it to be used only once. Is there some rules that can be referenced to it being able to be used more than once or something?

Comment: @Ryu133 It sounds like the CB and Compendium have written the power confusingly. The original is available in the article "Class Acts: The Duelist Rogue" by Mike Mearls in *Dragon* #381.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Thank you! That might be what I need!

Comment: +1, @Ryu133 I'm looking at a copy of DM381, and this answer is correct. The secondary attack is not specified as a daily, only the stance. It wouldn't hurt this answer to note that you can't take immediate actions on your own turn. This means that you cannot make the attack in response to an opportunity attack you provoke while making your normal move.

Comment: @DCShannon the only problem with the DM version is that it does not have the weapon keyword in it which is why I think they split it into a secondary power in the Character Builder and Compendium and maybe trying to make it easier to understand but failing at that part,