# Do follow-up attacks granted by daily powers count as daily powers for feats?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, balance, attack, powers

Some feats affect daily powers, and some daily powers grant extra attacks. For example, [Dazing Fist](http://iws.mx/dnd/?view=feat3339) (Psionic Power) is a feat that says:

> When you hit an enemy with a daily attack power, you also daze the enemy (save ends).

[Calm Before the Storm](http://iws.mx/dnd/?view=power16156) (*Heroes of the Elemental Chaos*) is a daily attack power that says:

> "Until the stance ends... you can use the secondary power at will."

[Elsewhere on this StackExchange](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/60447/can-you-use-the-duelist-prowess-attack-power-only-once-during-combat-in-4e), it was suggested that stance powers don't count as daily attacks since it was clearly rules-as-intended that the power should be usable more than once in the stance.

However, for the purposes of Dazing Fist, does hitting with the stance power count as hitting with the overall daily power, thus creating a stance that dazes? It has the "daily" keyword in the description. From the *Rules Compendium*, page 97 (emphasis mine):

> Some powers encompass what are called secondary powers. A creature must use the encompassing power to gain access to the secondary power.... If a secondary power has keywords that differ from those of the encompassing power, its keywords are noted in parentheses. **Otherwise, the secondary power has the same keywords.**

A related-but-not-identical example is [Lightning Daggers](http://iws.mx/dnd/?view=power3043) (Arcane Power), with the following effect:

> Until the end of the encounter, you can repeat the attack as a free action once per round during your turn.

You're repeating a daily power. Is the repeat also a daily power? This is different than a stance but it's a related question.

Another example is most Warden powers, such as [Form of the Living Breach](http://iws.mx/dnd/?view=power11094) (*Dragon* 383), which grants a follow-up attack with the following description.

> Once during this encounter, you can use the Living Breach Attack power.

Does that make the Living Breach Attack an encounter power, or a daily power? Or... somehow neither?

From the *Player's Handbook*, page 55:

> A power’s keyword entry gives you important rules information about the power. The first keyword indicates whether the power is an at-will, encounter, or daily power. (One example of each type is given above.) The color used in the line containing the power name also conveys this information: At-will powers have a green bar, encounter powers have a red bar, and daily powers have a black bar.

**QUASI-COUNTEREXAMPLE:** In all previously listed cases, follow-up attacks are in the same box as the daily keyword. This is distinctly different than the *Offline Compendium*'s write-up of [Refire the Forge](http://iws.mx/dnd/?view=power12206) (*Dragon* 385), where the stance grants access to a power that has the At-Will keyword:

> Until the stance ends you can use the power Refire the Forge Attack, at will.

And a green box follows, with the At-Will keyword. However, in the original Dragon 385 article, it says "until the stance ends you can make the following at-will attack," and does not have a green box with the At-Will keyword. The *Offline Compendium* is usually pretty good with keeping up with updates, so I didn't know if this was something had changed before Wizards' 4e Compendium got shut down.

Answer (score 3):

### It works on attacks that happen once per day

I think the core idea is what is expressed in the first sentence of Daily Powers (p. 54 PHB):

> **A daily power can be used once per day**. Daily powers are the most powerful effects you can produce, and using one takes a significant toll on your physical and mental resources.

As you point out, most daily powers contain additional effects:

> Daily powers usually include **an effect that takes place regardless of whether the power is used successfully**. As a result, these limited resources are at least slightly beneficial every time you use them. Once you use a daily power, you need to take an extended rest (page 263) before you can use it again.

This is to not make the daily power a total disappointment if you happen to miss. For balance, if these additional effects allow you to make multiple attacks, they should not benefit from boosters that are meant for a once daily attack. This is the logic of [the Q&A you cite](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/60447/can-you-use-the-duelist-prowess-attack-power-only-once-during-combat-in-4e).

Multiple attacks you can make as a secondary effect are not the daily attack power's attack. The daily power's attack is the thing that is listed with the **Attack:** type, and a hit for it is described under the **Hit:** entry. When the feat says "*When you hit an enemy with a daily attack power*" it talks about getting this Hit: result, and that is what you apply Daze to. Maybe more importantly, it should be something that happens only **once a day**.

So, you would not apply the feat to attacks from Secondary Powers that allow you to make multiple attacks (like Calm Before the Storm's secondary power) or to extra attacks granted by its additional effect (like Lightning Daggers' effect). However, as you can only make one Living Breach Attack per day with Form of the Living Breach, it also has the Daily usage keyword, and provides a Hit: entry, I think the feat should apply to it and it should Daze if you hit.

PS. Living Breach Attack is clearly a Daily power -- you can only use it *once per day*, and its usage keyword is Daily. Every power can only be used in an encounter, that does not make it an Encounter power. What makes an Encounter power an Encounter power is if you can use it *once per encounter*, but multiple encounters per day.